# How to fire a custom event from router guard in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to display message based on whether the navigation was successful or not to the user.

I created a router guard to prevent user from accessing path based on certain conditions.

However, I do not understand how do I emit **custom events/behaviors** from router guard so that a component can subscribe to it?

I tried following answer from `https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14404`

```
As a workaround you can emit custom events yourself:

constructor(private router: Router) {}
canDeactivate() {
   (<any>this.router).routerEvents.next(new MyCustomCanDeactivateEvent());
 return true;
}
```

But not sure how do I create **MyCustomCanDeactivateEvent**? And also it uses **private routerEvents** property of *Router* class.

Is there any better alternative to it? Perhaps using **BehaviorSubject**?

Comment: Yes using `behaviour subject` is the way to go i:e a [shared service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh, however I do not see any use of _behavior subject_ as per my question in the plunker.

Comment: that was a wrong link a small demo on shred services

Comment: BTW, your link says `Currently Angular has no implementation of Interceptors`, it already has interceptor https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: yes it a old text in that very page you have interceptors explained , i need to change that forgot i guess :P and that was a different question altogether . thanks will update . if you need to know about interceptors check this on the same page https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services

Comment: Thx buddy. We digress! :)